# Copy DynamoDB query to Redshift

Tags: copy, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to copy a portion of the data from a DynamoDB table to Redshift.
I know that I can use something like the following to copy the entire table and it's working:

```
COPY some_table from 'dynamodb://some_ddb_table' 
credentials 'aws_iam_role=some_role' readratio 50;
```

However I'm looking for something like the following to copy only a portion of the data (where X=Y in this case):

```
COPY some_table from 'dynamodb://some_ddb_table where X=Y' 
credentials 'aws_iam_role=some_role' readratio 50;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: no, not directly. you could unload the filtered version to s3 first, then load the s3 into redshift

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How do I upload the filtered version to S3?

Comment: i have used data pipeline for this, which can then be streamed together with a load to redshift (copy command) step http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use data pipeline for this as you mentioned but having trouble filtering out only X=Y ('X' would be the partition key, so I'm expecting this query to be fast as well). Do you know how to filter out when copying?